# realloc across threads in c

Tags: c, multithreading, realloc

I am having difficulty with reallocating some memory to store a larger string. This is allocating the memory on one thread and then passing it to another.  The other thread then does some processing and changes the string.  The issue is it cannot update the string and fails.  I have not got much experiance with C and definately think I have missed something or put something wrong.

Here is some example code.

```
//Struct to store options for passing across threads
typedef struct options{
    char *host;
//other options here
} options;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //set initial options
    options *opt;
    opt->host = malloc(strlen(argv[0])*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(opt->host,argv[0]);

    //set variables for thread
    void *pData;
    DWORD dwThreadId;
    HANDLE hThread = NULL;

    //allocate memory for thread
    pData = malloc(sizeof(options));
    memcpy(pData, opt, sizeof(options));

    //create thread
    hThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,WorkerThread,pData,0,&dwThreadId);
    if (hThread ==NULL) //thread not started
         exit(1);

    //wait for thread
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread,   //Address of thread
                    INFINITE); //Timeout value

    //close thread and free memory
    CloseHandle(hThread);
    if (pData != NULL){
        //not sure why I did it this way
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pData);
        pData = NULL;
    }
    if (opt != NULL){
        free(opt);
    }
    return 0;
}

//Our worker thread to change the string
DWORD WINAPI WorkerThread(void *pOpt)
{
    //get passed parameters
    options *opt = (options*) malloc(sizeof(options));
    memcpy(opt,pOpt,sizeof(options));

    //change the text of passed option
    char text[10] = "Some text";
    opt->host = (char*)realloc(opt->host,sizeof(text)*sizeof(char));
    //code crashes on line above
    strncpy(opt->host,text,sizeof(text));
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `opt->host = malloc(strlen(argv[0])*sizeof(char));` - `Opt`  has not been initialised!

Answer (score 6):

This triggers undefined behavior, twice:

```
    options *opt;
    opt->host = malloc(strlen(argv[0])*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(opt->host,argv[0]);
```

The second line is UB since `opt` is not initialized, so you cannot assign to `opt->host`.

Then you miscalculate storage required for a string, by failing to add 1 for the terminator, so the `strcpy()` line causes UB again by writing out of bounds.

Fix the allocations by doing:

```
opt = malloc(sizeof *opt);
opt->host = malloc(strlen(argv[0]) + 1);
```

There's no need to scale by `sizeof(char)`, that's always 1.

Also this in the thread function:

```
//get passed parameters
options *opt = (options*) malloc(sizeof(options));
memcpy(opt,pOpt,sizeof(options));
```

could just be

```
options opt = *pOpt;
```

No need to dynamically allocate that, and never any need to `memcpy()` structures, they're values and can be assigned.

Take care not to race with the `realloc()`, if another thread is doing the same thing at the same time there will be trouble I think.

Comment: To add to @unwind's answer: 
@Dave Griffiths - Just be careful when using `strncpy` it will not auto null-terminate if the string does not fit. It may be a good idea to use #defines for example:

    `#define STRING_SIZE  (20)`
    `#define STRING_LEN (STRING_SIZE -1)`


Then use 
`strncpy(opt->host, text, STRING_LEN); opt->host[STRING_LEN] = '\0';`

refer: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/

Comment: Or you can just use [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html).

Comment: @Mrunmoy That's a lot of macros. Not my way, it's better to avoid `strncpy()` since it's so weird. And yes like Andrew said, if you have it (it's not standard!) you can use `strdup()` for this.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, issue was due to cross threading as the data was trying to be maniplutated across two threads at the same time.